# How to redirect MacBook 2009 audio to my Sony TV?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, audio, television

I can't connect audio from my MacBook 2009 to a Sony HD LED TV, need some help.

Answer (score 1):

2009 MacBook Pro's do not output audio through the display port.  This feature didn't start until the 2010 models.  You will need a second optical cable or headphone cable from the audio port.